# Postgres function is not working/calling in hosted web project

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an ASP.Net Core Web App (MVC) Project which in turns call Web Api for calling the database for getting the values and posting the values. The database used is Postgres. I have written a Postgres function to populate values for a report Day Book. When I run the project through visual studio it works fine. Then I have hosted the project. When I login through hosted ip address and calling the report function returns no values and the reports showing no values.
The Postgres function is given below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.day_book(
d1 date,
d2 date,
cid integer)
RETURNS TABLE(roworder integer, guid uuid, tbl1 text, date1 timestamp without time zone, credit real, debit real, description1 text, credit1 real, debit1 real) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    
RETURN QUERY 
SELECT db1."roworder",db1."guid",db1."tbl1",db1."date1",db1."credit",db1."debit",
db1."description1",db1."credit1",db1."debit1"
from "tbldaybook1" as db1 order by db1."date1",db1."roworder";

END;
$BODY$;
```

The MVC controller method that calls the API controller method is given below

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetDayBook(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
        var currentUserId = Convert.ToInt32(currentUser.FindFirst("UserId").Value);
        var ChurchId = Convert.ToInt32(currentUser.FindFirst("ChurchId").Value);
        var Role = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
        var isSuperAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(currentUser.FindFirst("IsSuperAdmin").Value);

        var d11 = FromDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        var d22 = ToDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        int cid = ChurchId;

        List<RptDayBook> daybook = new List<RptDayBook>();
        HttpClient client = api.Initial();
        HttpResponseMessage responseTask = await client.GetAsync("reports/GetDayBook/" + d11 + "/" + d22 + "/" + cid);
        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var readTask = responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            daybook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RptDayBook>>(readTask);
        }
        return Json(daybook);            
    }
```

The below API method connects to the Postgres database and call the function

```
[HttpGet("GetDayBook/{d11}/{d22}/{cid}")]
    public IEnumerable<RptDayBook> GetDayBook(string d11, string d22, int cid)
    {
        using (var command = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(d11);
            DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(d22).AddDays(1);

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.CommandText = "day_book";
            command.Parameters.Add(new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("d1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date)
            { Value = d1 });
            command.Parameters.Add(new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("d2", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date)
            { Value = d2 });
            command.Parameters.Add(new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("cid", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
            { Value = cid });
            if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                command.Connection.Open();
            List<object[]> result = new List<object[]>();
            var res = command.ExecuteReader();                
            if (res.HasRows)
            {
                while (res.Read())
                {
                    var values = new object[res.FieldCount];
                    for (int i = 0; i < res.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 8)
                        {
                            values[i] = res[i] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(res[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            values[i] = res[i];
                        }
                    }
                    result.Add(values);
                }
            }

            List<RptDayBook> rpt = new List<RptDayBook>();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                RptDayBook rptDayBook = new RptDayBook();
                rptDayBook.roworder = (int)item[0];
                rptDayBook.GUID = (Guid)item[1];
                rptDayBook.tbl1 = (string)item[2];
                rptDayBook.date1 = (DateTime)item[3];
                rptDayBook.credit = item[4] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(item[4]);
                rptDayBook.debit = item[5] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(item[5]);
                rptDayBook.Description1 = (string)item[6];
                rptDayBook.credit1 = item[7] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(item[7]);
                rptDayBook.debit1 = item[8] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(item[8]);

                rpt.Add(rptDayBook);
            }
            return rpt;
        }
    }
```

What will be the issue? Is it either the function is not calling or function can't return values?

Comment: check the connection

Comment: Connection is correct because other data from the database are showing in the project. Only the function calling is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue while converting the datetime in the API.
Change the code from
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(d11);
to
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(d11, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Also do the same in the next line also.